# adding XML to an arraylist that has a non repeating pattern Java

Tags: java, xml, arraylist

I have XML data fed through from an API

The data is similar to below

```
<item>
 <A>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</A>
 <B>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</B>
 <C>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</C>
 <D>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</D>
 </item>
<item>
<item>
 <A>rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</A>
 <B>rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</B>
 <C>rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</C>
 <D>rrrrrrrrrrrrrr</D>
 </item>
<item>
<item>
 <A>rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</A>
 <B>rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</B>
 <C>rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</C>
 <D>rrrrrrrrrrrrrr</D>
 <E>rrrrrrrrrrrrrr</E>
 </item>
<item>
```

x and r represents data for each particular element.

Below is an extract of my code,
I am adding each element of each node into an arraylist using the following bit of code, a,b,c,d are the arraylists:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
Element element = (Element)list.item(i);
String nodeName = element.getNodeName();

switch (nodeName) {
case "A":
a.add(element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()); 
break;
case "B":
b.add(element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()); 
break;
case "C":
c.add(element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()); 
break;
case "D":
d.add(element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()); 
break;
case "E":
e.add(element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()); 
break;
```

The problem is that the XML structure adds node E to the structure in this repeating list partway down the XML. This causes a problem because the lengths of my arraylists are now differing in length. When it comes to comparing arraylists or creating tables of the arraylists the data is not aligned because of the differing lengths. What can i do so that all the arraylists are the same length. I wish to do this as an arraylist.

Comment: use `HashSet` instead to avoid duplication

Comment: Recognize the case where no 'e' was seen before the end of the 'item', and add a null or dummy value to the corresponding araylist to occupy that space.

Comment: @ keshlam how would i do this?

Comment: Look at my post: Look at how each setter should be defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Synchronizing lists does not seem a good practice. If you want all the lists have *the same size*, that means that, conceptually, you want *just one list*. So, redesign your code to match the right concept:

Instead of several lists of beans:

```
List<A> a;
List<B> b;
List<C> c;
...
```

... why don't replace it with a single list of a composite bean:

```
class MyComposite
{
    private A a;
    private B b;
    private C c;

    public A getA()
    {
        return this.a;
    }

    public void setA(A a)
    {
        this.a=a;
    }

    // ... rest of getters and setters...
}

List<MyComposite> list;
```

So, the population algorithm would be like this:

```
// Iterate over the "item" nodes of the document:
private List<MyComposite> populate(Document doc)
{
    NodeList items=doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
    List<MyComposite> list=new ArrayList<MyComposite>(items.getLength());
    for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++)
    {
        Element item = (Element)items.item(i);
        MyComposite myComposite=parseItem(item);
        list.add(myComposite);
    }
    return list;
}

// Create one MyComposite bean reading the child nodes of an input "item" node:
private MyComposite parseItem(Element item)
{
    MyComposite myComposite=new MyComposite();
    NodeList childNodes=item.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++)
    {
        // Processing some element in the form: <name>value</name>
        Element element = (Element)childNodes.item(i);
        String nodeName = element.getNodeName();
        String nodeValue = element.getTextContent();

        // Decide where to store the node value (in myComposite) depending on the node name:
        switch (nodeName)
        {
            case "A":
                myComposite.setA(nodeValue); 
                break;
            case "B":
                myComposite.setB(nodeValue); 
                break;
            ...
            default: // An unknown node was found.
                System.err.println("Warning: Node '"+nodeName+"' not recognized and will be ignored");
        }
    }
    return myComposite;
}
```

In this way, you can have the XML loaded into a coherent data model with no chance of lists with different sizes.

Comment: @ Little Santi, hi thanks for your response I will experiment with this, i am relatively new to Java so i will try get this to work but i may have to revert.

Comment: @ Little Santi a quick question why does A, B, and C appear underlined in red in its current form?
 
class MyComposite
{
    private A a;
    private B b;
    private C c;
    // ... getters and setters...
}

List<MyComposite> list;

Comment: Are private A a; private B b;private C c; strings?

Comment: I meant A, B and C to be any type you want, even if they have to be _different_ types. Of corse, it is easier they being strings, so the can be got from node values immediately. Should they be other types, a conversion must be done after reading the node values.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, i shall try get this to work

Comment: @  Little Santi I need a more thorough help with this question. As i am a sort of newbie i havent really got the understanding how the getters and setters work. I have put a bounty of 50 on this if you would care to have a comprehensive working answer, covering the full question?

Comment: _Getter_ is a kind of method to read the value of a private variable, and _setter_ a kind of method to write it. I've included an example in my answer. It is a standard in java to have a getter and a setter for every [private] variable in a class. More than the bounty, I rather that you ask every single issue you don't understand.

Comment: @ Little Santi This is my aim, i want to understand. I will have a look through your work, but the first thing that strikes me is that element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue(); doesnt appear anywhere but element.getTextContent() does. Where does it specify, for example, that case "A" will get the node value of "A"?

Comment: @ Little Santi following on from this                                                           case "A":                                         myComposite.setA(element.getTextContent()); 
break;                                                                                                            Assuming case A is working in the same way ie.getting the content of the node, and then setting as setA. Does setA need to be defined somewhere as it appears out of the blue? and if so how do i do this?

Comment: Ups. My mistake. I've caressly mixed the two necessary levels of browsing. Sorry! I've updated my algorithm separating both loops and explaining what does each one. And about `getTextContent`, I've put it on purpose: It's a shortcut API to get the full text content of some node.

Comment: @ Little Santi thanks for your update, as i am getting the length of the arraylist should List<MyComposite> list=new ArrayList<MyComposite>(items.size()); be replaced with List<MyComposite> list=new ArrayList<MyComposite>(items.getlength());?

Comment: Oh, yes. A typo of mine.

Comment: @ Little Santi, many thanks i will continue to study the code

Comment: @ Little Santi my next question is within the class MyComposite private A a; private B a; etc refers to the node A, B etc and assigned to a, b etc  but why does A,B appear underlined in red by Java?

Comment: No, it isn't: Replace "A", "B" and "C" by whatever types you want. For example, String. Replace A by String, B by String and C by String.

Comment: Oh i see, i was getting carried away by the naming of the items and i presumed incorrectly.

Comment: @ Little Santi I get an underlined red error when i place nodeValue inside () such as below, but if i leave it empty it appears okay why?  case "A":
                myComposite.setA(nodeValue); 
                break;

Comment: @ Little Santi I am looking to print out my data into the console so i can what i have done so far and if it is working, in a normal array list i would use something along the lines of for(int index = 0;index<list.size();index++){System.println(list.get(index));} where would i place this to get a print out and would it work in the same way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88625/discussion-between-little-santi-and-mr-assistance).

Answer (score 0):

Add dummy or null value in the respective list if node with that name is not found. This will keep all arraylist length equal.

Comment: @ Raman Shrivastava could you provide some code on how i would do that?

Comment: @ Raman Shrivastava and if i did place an if statement where would i put it because the nodename determines which case is used, if the nodename doesnt state E at what point would i say now fill in a dummy value?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the endgame of your "action", as implied in "**When it comes to comparing arraylists or creating tables of the arraylists the data is not aligned because of the differing lengths**", is to store data into database the answer is simple..
Batched Prepared Statement.. these beauties are perfect for doing massive amount of work that is repetitive in nature..
Simply create 5 (n) prepared statement and add batch as you see fit, giving the name of the element, the value of the element and a father key (e.g. the "id" of the relevant item element) and add the "prepared" insert to the batch of the relevant prepared statement.. than execute the whole lot and there you have it, alignement taken care of for free as well ...
A sample code of how i would envision this (long, but maybe it will give you some ideas..)... In the sample all prepared statement do the very same thing, but I'm giving four different "actor" method, so that you can basically customize the target query for each different "element" of the item type. Additionally you should plan a full rollback method, as with this "thing" you will commit each block (preparedstatement) when the cap of queryLimit (10000) is reached, so for rolling back you will need to do a manual method cleaning the relevant item (e.g. adding for example a "referral" id of the xml that originated the elements iteselves).

```
        public class ExternalQueryInputAnnex {

    private int queryLimit = 10000;

        //prep statement for elementA
        private PreparedStatement ps1;
        private int cnt1 = 0;
        //prep statement for elementB
        private PreparedStatement ps2;
        private int cnt2 = 0;
        //prep statement for elementC
        private PreparedStatement ps3;
        private int cnt3 = 0;
        //prep statement for elementD
        private PreparedStatement ps4;
        private int cnt4 = 0;
        //prep statement for elementE
        private PreparedStatement ps5;
        private int cnt5 = 0;


        private void theThingYouNeed(List<Object> itemList)
        {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
            Element element = (Element)list.item(i);
            String nodeName = element.getNodeName();

            switch (nodeName) {
                case "A":
                doPreparedStatementOne("element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()", "A", "whatever");
                break;
                case "B":
                doPreparedStatementTwo("element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()", "B", "whatever");
                break;
                case "C":
                doPreparedStatementThree("element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()", "C", "whatever");
                break;
                case "D":
                doPreparedStatementFour("element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()", "D", "whatever");
                break;
                case "E":
                //e.add(element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()); 
                doPreparedStatementFive("element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()", "E", "whatever");
                break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void doPreparedStatementFive(String attribute, String sonId, String fatherId) throws DatabaseException {

            int i = 0;

            String query = "INSERT INTO TRS_ORDER_PRICE_INT_DTL_TIMES "
                    + "(SON_VALUE,SON_ID,FATHER_ID) "
                    + "VALUES "
                    + "(?,?,?)";            
            try {
                if (ps5 == null)
                {
                    ps5 = connect.prepareStatement(query);
                }

                ps5.setString(1, attribute);
                ps5.setString(2, sonId);
                ps5.setString(3, fatherId);
                ps5.addBatch();
                cnt5++;
                if (cnt5 >= queryLimit)
                    {
                        ps5 = wrapperDoBulkQueryList(ps5, query);
                        cnt5 = 0;
                    }
                }

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error("Error insertOrderPriceIntDtlTimes: "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
                throw new DatabaseException("Sql Exception during insertOrderPriceIntDtlTimes: "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }

        private void doPreparedStatementFour(String attribute, String sonId, String fatherId) throws DatabaseException {

            int i = 0;

            String query = "INSERT INTO TRS_ORDER_PRICE_INT_DTL_TIMES "
                    + "(SON_VALUE,SON_ID,FATHER_ID) "
                    + "VALUES "
                    + "(?,?,?)";            
            try {
                if (ps4 == null)
                {
                    ps4 = connect.prepareStatement(query);
                }

                ps4.setString(1, attribute);
                ps4.setString(2, sonId);
                ps4.setString(3, fatherId);
                ps4.addBatch();
                cnt4++;
                if (cnt4 >= queryLimit)
                    {
                        ps4 = wrapperDoBulkQueryList(ps4, query);
                        cnt4 = 0;
                    }
                }

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error("Error insertOrderPriceIntDtlTimes: "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
                throw new DatabaseException("Sql Exception during insertOrderPriceIntDtlTimes: "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }

        private void doPreparedStatementThree(String attribute, String sonId, String fatherId) throws DatabaseException {

            int i = 0;

            String query = "INSERT INTO TRS_ORDER_PRICE_INT_DTL_TIMES "
                    + "(SON_VALUE,SON_ID,FATHER_ID) "
                    + "VALUES "
                    + "(?,?,?)";            
            try {
                if (ps3 == null)
                {
                    ps3 = connect.prepareStatement(query);
                }

                ps3.setString(1, attribute);
                ps3.setString(2, sonId);
                ps3.setString(3, fatherId);
                ps3.addBatch();
                cnt3++;
                if (cnt3 >= queryLimit)
                    {
                        ps3 = wrapperDoBulkQueryList(ps3, query);
                        cnt3 = 0;
                    }
                }

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error("Error insertOrderPriceIntDtlTimes: "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
                throw new DatabaseException("Sql Exception during insertOrderPriceIntDtlTimes: "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }

        private void doPreparedStatementTwo(String attribute, String sonId, String fatherId) throws DatabaseException {

            int i = 0;

            String query = "INSERT INTO TRS_ORDER_PRICE_INT_DTL_TIMES "
                    + "(SON_VALUE,SON_ID,FATHER_ID) "
                    + "VALUES "
                    + "(?,?,?)";            
            try {
                if (ps2 == null)
                {
                    ps2 = connect.prepareStatement(query);
                }

                ps2.setString(1, attribute);
                ps2.setString(2, sonId);
                ps2.setString(3, fatherId);
                ps2.addBatch();
                cnt2++;
                if (cnt2 >= queryLimit)
                    {
                        ps2 = wrapperDoBulkQueryList(ps2, query);
                        cnt2 = 0;
                    }
                }

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error("Error insertOrderPriceIntDtlTimes: "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
                throw new DatabaseException("Sql Exception during insertOrderPriceIntDtlTimes: "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }

        private void doPreparedStatementOne(String attribute, String sonId, String fatherId) throws DatabaseException {

            int i = 0;

            String query = "INSERT INTO TRS_ORDER_PRICE_INT_DTL_TIMES "
                    + "(SON_VALUE,SON_ID,FATHER_ID) "
                    + "VALUES "
                    + "(?,?,?)";            
            try {
                if (ps1 == null)
                {
                    ps1 = connect.prepareStatement(query);
                }

                ps1.setString(1, attribute);
                ps1.setString(2, sonId);
                ps1.setString(3, fatherId);
                ps1.addBatch();
                cnt1++;
                if (cnt1 >= queryLimit)
                    {
                        ps1 = wrapperDoBulkQueryList(ps1, query);
                        cnt1 = 0;
                    }
                }

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error("Error insertOrderPriceIntDtlTimes: "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
                throw new DatabaseException("Sql Exception during insertOrderPriceIntDtlTimes: "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }

        // do any sub-querylimit execution
        public void cleanUpExecution() throws DatabaseException
        {
            if (ps1 != null)
            {
                logger.debug("ps1");
                wrapperDoBulkQueryList(ps1, null);
            }
            if (ps2 != null)
            {
                logger.debug("ps2");
                wrapperDoBulkQueryList(ps2, null);
            }
            if (ps3 != null)
            {
                logger.debug("ps3");
                wrapperDoBulkQueryList(ps3, null);
            }
            if (ps4 != null)
            {
                logger.debug("ps4");
                wrapperDoBulkQueryList(ps4, null);
            }
            if (ps5 != null)
            {
                logger.debug("ps5");
                wrapperDoBulkQueryList(ps5, null);
            }
        }

        public PreparedStatement wrapperDoBulkQueryList(PreparedStatement queryBulk, String query) throws DatabaseException
        {

            queryBulk = wrapperDoBulkQueryListDirect(queryBulk, null, query);
            return queryBulk;
        }

        public PreparedStatement wrapperDoBulkQueryListDirect(PreparedStatement queryList, Long load_id, String query) throws DatabaseException
        {
            if (doBulkQueryList(queryList))
            {
                if (query != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        queryList = connect.prepareStatement(query);
                        return queryList;
                    }
                    catch (SQLException e)
                    {
                        throw new DatabaseException("Exception of sqlexception while regenerating statement:"+e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    logger.debug("Query not passed, cleanup for preparedstatement");
                    //System.out.println("Query not passed, cleanup for preparedstatement");
                    return queryList;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // do delete based on loadid
                // then throw exception
                throw new DatabaseException("Some failure");
            }
        }

        public boolean doBulkQueryList(PreparedStatement queryList) throws DatabaseException
        {
            // do bulk query execution
            try {
                connect.setAutoCommit(false);
                //System.out.println("query: "+singleQuery.toString());
                long startSetup = System.currentTimeMillis();
                int[] results = queryList.executeBatch();
                long finishSetup = (System.currentTimeMillis()-startSetup)/1000;
                if(finishSetup > 5){
                    logger.warn("Execution "+results.length+" insert in "+finishSetup+" seconds.");
                }


                for(int singleResult : results){
                    if (singleResult >= 0) {
                        // System.out.println("OK; updateCount");
                    }
                    else if (singleResult == Statement.SUCCESS_NO_INFO) {
                        // System.out.println("OK; insert=Statement.SUCCESS_NO_INFO");
                    }
                    else if (singleResult == Statement.EXECUTE_FAILED) {
                        System.out.println("Failure; updateCount=Statement.EXECUTE_FAILED");
                    }
                }

                insertedRows = insertedRows + results.length;
                //System.out.println("Query effettuata");
                connect.commit();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
                if (connect != null) {
                    try {
                        logger.error("Transaction is being rolled back: ",e);

                        connect.rollback();
                        return false;
                    } catch(SQLException excep) {

                        throw new DatabaseException("Error Transaction commit");
                    }

                }
            }
            finally{
                if (queryList != null) {
                    try {
                        queryList.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {

                        logger.error("Transaction is being rolled back: "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }
                try {
                    connect.setAutoCommit(true);
                } catch (SQLException e) {

                    logger.error("Set true auto commit: ",e);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your xml is proper with proper root tag, the easiest approach would be to use Jaxb. Since JDK 1.6 JaxB comes out of the box. The code would be short and simple like

```
File file = new File("Item.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Items.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Items items = (Items) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(dBuilder.parse(file));
```

A complete example. Say your xml is like

```
<items>
    <item>
        <A>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</A>
        <B>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</B>
        <C>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</C>
        <D>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</D>
    </item>
    <item>
        <A>rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</A>
        <B>rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</B>
        <C>rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</C>
        <D>rrrrrrrrrrrrrr</D>
    </item>
    <item>
        <A>rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</A>
        <B>rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</B>
        <C>rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</C>
        <D>rrrrrrrrrrrrrr</D>
        <E>rrrrrrrrrrrrrr</E>
    </item>
</items>
```

Then you need to create 2 class one parent `Items` and child `Item` (or whatever name you like).

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

@XmlRootElement(name = "items")
class Items implements Serializable {
    List<Item> item;

    public List<Item> getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "item")
    public void setItem(List<Item> item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Items [" + item + "]";
    }
}

class Item implements Serializable {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
    private String d;
    private String e;

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "A")
    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "B")
    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getC() {
        return c;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "C")
    public void setC(String c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public String getD() {
        return d;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "D")
    public void setD(String d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    public String getE() {
        return e;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "E")
    public void setE(String e) {
        this.e = e;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item [a=" + a + ", b=" + b + ", c=" + c + ", d=" + d + ", e="
                + e + "]";
    }
}

public class ItemParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("Item.xml"); // Give appropriate file path.
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Items.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Items items = (Items) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(dBuilder.parse(file));
        System.out.println(items);
    }
}
```